# iPhone Enterprise app push updates to users?

Tags: iphone

If my company is a member of the Enterprise program where we can distribute apps internally for any number of users is there a good way to handle app updates? Everything I see on installing such apps is saying I have to send the .app and a profile to the end users for them to add to iTunes and then sync their device to install. Is there any way to have the user's computer or device know when I have an update to the app available or do I just have to redistribute the app file manually again and hope for everyone to update manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can update configuration profiles over-the-air, it doesn’t appear that you can do this. Your best bet would be to implement a notification in your app when it starts to tell the users to upgrade. See the [Enterprise Deployment Guide](https://ssl.apple.com/ie/iphone/business/docs/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks

Comment: The link to enterprise Deployment Guide is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late to answer this, but I'm facing the exact same problem.
After spending some time looking for a solution we've come to the conclusion that this can be done in two ways:

1. You can achieve a lot of things with a Mobile Device Management (MDM) server. You can force installation of applications, and perhaps this can work if you want to update. You can collect information on what version the app is running, and then perhaps directly target users with outdated versions of the app: http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_MDM.pdf I don't have access to an MDM, so I haven't tried this out.
2. Finally, build in some kind of deprecation functionality that tells the user to update. This is what apple recommends ( http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad802c ) (and the solution we are going for).